# How can I select rows from 3 tables with link table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
| Store            | Address | Category    | link             |
|   id             |   id    |   id        |   fk_categoryID  |
|   fk_addressID   |   city  |   category  |   fk_storeID     |
```

I want to select all stores with address that has category A.

I use this to find stores in a specific city:

```
SELECT a.name, b.street1, b.street2, b.city
FROM store a
JOIN address b ON b.id = a.fk_addressID
WHERE b.city = 'oslo'
```

Now I just need to add category criteria.

I can't remember how to do that. Adding another INNER or LEFT join for the link table works, but I get 7-10 rows for each store found.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT s.id AS "Store ID", a.id AS "Address ID", a.city AS "City", c.category AS "Category" FROM store s
LEFT JOIN address a ON a.id = s.fk_addressID
LEFT JOIN link l on l.fk_storeID = s.id
LEFT JOIN category c on c.id = l.fk_categoryID
WHERE a.city = "oslo" AND c.category = "A";
```

Let me know if that helps!

**EDIT**

Recreated the schema on my computer, added some test data, ran the SQL and got the following:

[image]